# How do you solve this series question? : $\cos (n\pi )/ \ln(6n) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem is, Select the FIRST correct reason on the list why the given series converges.

A. Geometric series 
B. Comparison with a convergent p series
C. Integral test 
D. Ratio test 
E. Alternating series test

I understand all the other sub problems except for this one:

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\ln(6n)}$$

The answer is E, Alternating series test. The alternating series test is what you do if an alternating series doesn't converge absolutely using the absolute convergence test right? Anyways, I'm a little stumped on how to solve this problem.

My first thought was to take the absolute value of it, which means $\cos(n\pi)\leq 0$. Therefore the original sum was $\leq \frac{1}{\ln(6n)}$ ... Bla!

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The value of $\cos(n\pi)$ is actually rather simple, you might start by computing it.

Comment: crap! didn't see that. But that leaves it to (-1)^n / ln(6n) still right? the absolute value is 1/ln(6n)... which diverges, but i don't know how to prove it

Comment: Looks like the integral test is supposed to work... goin to try that real quick

Comment: Alright so my real question should be "How do you prove that the integral from 1 to infinity of 1/ln(6x) diverges?"

Comment: I figured it out! 1/ln(6x) ~ 1 / ln(x) > 1 / n which diverges by the p test. Yay!

Comment: Why don't you post your answer as "an answer" - seriously!  It's always nice to see those asking questions willing and able to continue working on answering them...Feel free to post how you arrived at your answer (reasoning), as well!

Comment: @Silver: Careful!  If you look up *integral test* you will find that the standard form of it is for functions that are *non-negative*.  In the case of this series, that condition fails.  With some manipulation, you could turn it into something to which the integral test applies, but I expect the question-setter didn't think of that.

Comment: Since $\cos (n\pi )=(-1)^{n}$, the series is

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln (6n)}$

Comment: The divergence of the _series_ $\Sigma 1/\ln(6n)$ is somewhat moot here; it's true that that series diverges (and you can convince yourself that A and B don't apply easily, and that D doesn't apply with a little bit more effort.  You do need the divergence of that series to show that the interval test doesn't work, but the reason why the alternating series test works is simply that the _sequence_ $1/\ln(6n)$ converges monotonically to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit in response to Robert Israel's comment.*

Since $\cos (n\pi )=(-1)^{n}$, the series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\ln (6n)},$$

which converges by the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) because $\frac{1}{\ln (6n)}\rightarrow 0$ *and $1/\ln(6n)$ is monotone decreasing*.

But

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\ln (6n)}$$

is not convergent because:

1. so is

   $$\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{\log (6x)},$$

   as can be seen by the limit test with $$\int_{1}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{6x},$$

   applying L'Hôpital's rule.
2. *Or by a direct comparison test with the divergent series* $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{6n}$

   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\ln (6n)}\ge\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{6n},$$

   *because the harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.*

Comment: There's more to the alternating series test than $\frac{1}{\ln(6n)} \to 0$: you also need the fact that this sequence is monotonic. And you don't need to worry about integration: you can compare $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(6n)}$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{6n}$ directly, if you know that the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Thanks! I corrected the test for the 1st series and added the simpler test for the 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

The expected answer is of course E.  But for fun we show that things are slightly more complicated than that.  If the question were "what is the *simplest* test to use,"
the answer would be unambiguously E. But the question is about the *first* test in the list. A somewhat tongue in cheek case for C is made below.

Our series is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(6n)}.$$

For convenience, change all the signs.  So we are interested in
$$\left(\frac{1}{\ln(6)}-\frac{1}{\ln(12)}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{\ln(18)}-\frac{1}{\ln(24)}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{\ln(30)}-\frac{1}{\ln(36)}\right)+ \cdots.$$

Each group has shape
$$\frac{1}{\ln(12n+6)}-\frac{1}{\ln(12n+12)}.$$

Bring to a common denominator, then simplify the top. We get
$$\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)}{\ln(12n+6)\ln(12n+12)}.$$

But if $x$ is small positive, we have $0<\ln(1+x)<x$.
Now an easy **integral test** comparison with
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x(\ln x)^2}$$
shows that we have convergence.